# Use "time-slots" in a sentence

Tags: word-choice, time

> My apologies, but I am not available for the whole week of June 26. Could you please **give me** some time-slots for the following week?

> My apologies, but I am not available for the whole week of June 26. Could you please **propose** some time-slots for the following week?

Could you please tell me which one between the above sentences is correct? Is my usage of the word 'time-slots' correct?

Answer (score 1):

The way I would most likely use time-slots is as follows:

> ... Could you tell me which time-slots are available?

Comment: I agree (although this answer could be improved if you fleshed it out some more). I might say, “Could you please propose some **times** for the following week?”, or, “**Do you have** any time-slots for the following week?” but not “Could you propose some time-slots?” It’s a bit hard to explain _why_, but that explanation would likely be very helpful for the leaners.

Comment: It seems because of the core sense of verb 'propose', to intend to do something.